# Sed to Search 2 patterns, if the first pattern not exist, print the second pattern

Tags: sed

I have a question on sed. From this input:

```
[/=TueGreen$58.30Orange5:36pmSat*=WedOrange$76.63Purple6:20pmTue]
[/=Thu6:06pm$09.05Blue11:32amMon/=Thu1:38am$56.41Red4:25amThu]
[/=Sun1:49pm$12.41Yellow2:51pmMon*=FriOrange$49.68Blue1:24pmTue]
[/=Sat11:58am$82.24Orange3:44amMon*=Thu1:08am$33.49Red8:21amSat]
```

I have to make an Output:

```
$58.30
6:06pm$09.05
1:49pm$12.41
11:58am$82.24
```

I know, the pattern seems so easy, but, I'm even failed in finding the time pattern. Because the hour is sometimes 1 or 2 digits.

This is the third day I've been learning sed and looking for the answer. I've learned grep. So easy if using grep. But this assignment force me to use sed. So far, this is my sed command:

```
sed 's/.*\([0-9]*:[0-9]*\(am\|pm\)\).*/\1/' FILE
```

The results are only showing the minutes and am/pm. There are many time pattern in each line of the input. But my result shows the last time pattern in each line. As you see below:

```
:20pm
:25am
:24pm
:21am
```

Where did I go wrong?

Comment: +1 for very good first question, including sample data, expected output, current output, and .... gasp, an attempt by O.P. to have solved their own problem. Hmm, your title doesn't seem to match your description, but what the heck, its the holiday season. Good luck and keep posting!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here you go:

```
sed -e 's/[^$0-9]*\([0-9:]*[ap]m\)*\(\$[0-9.]*\).*/\1\2/'
```

Comment: Wow, thank you very much. This works. I will learn about this command. Thank you very much once again. You make my day. :)

Comment: Haha, you're welcome. I'm out of votes for today due to hat hunting, but I'll upvote your excellent question tomorrow ;-)

Comment: assuming there is always a value for fist "day" of the line (the case in the sample) and never a digit in element associate to the day (the color like it is the case in the sample). Very efficient sed

Comment: Hi, until now, I still don't understand what this [^$0-9]* means. Would you explain it to me, what does that means? I've looked somewhere else that $ is to look at the end of the line. Now, I've to search the pattern in the end of each line. But, I'm failed. Do you have any recommendation to learn regular expression? Thx.

Comment: `[^$0-9]` means NOT a `$` sign and NOT digits 0, 1, 2, ..., 9. Inside `[...]` most symbols lose their special meaning, that's why `$` there means a literal `$` sign instead of end-of-line.

Comment: Thank you. I finally finish almost all the important questions on my assignment. One more thing to ask: Can I sed an online document. Such as: sed 's/regexp/replacement/' <an online document file> example: sed 's/regexp/replacement/' http://stackoverflow.com/index.html. I couldn't do it. Or I don't know how to do it. I'd like to make a new threads because it seems no question like that has been asked. But, it looks like a very noob questions. (I know I'm a noob.) :D.

Comment: You could use a tool like `curl` which downloads a url and prints the content on standard output, so for example this will work: `curl stackoverflow.com | sed 's/regexp/replacement/'`